Tensorflow returning TypeError for no reason
I am trying to work with tensorflow_datasets library, the dataset I am working on is STL-10, but it doesn't matter much, because no matter what dataset I use, the same error is returned. I am using tensorflow 2.16.1
When I am running the following code, an error was returned.
ds = tfds.load('stl-10')

Exception ignored in: <function AtomicFunction.__del__ at 0x0000024C114AA160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\atomic_function.py", line 291, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Exception ignored in: <function AtomicFunction.__del__ at 0x0000024C114AA160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\atomic_function.py", line 291, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Exception ignored in: <function AtomicFunction.__del__ at 0x0000024C114AA160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\atomic_function.py", line 291, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Idk why the error is returned three times, but it did. I compared the file of atomic_function.py with the tensorflow library's file, those two are identical, I don't understand what was going on. But what went more absurd is when I run the code in the following way
tfds.load('stl-10')

When I didn't assign the dataset to a variable, there is no error returned.

Same problem here. Did you find a solution or a workaround?

Hi @Toby,you error shows that there is a version compatibility issue between tensorflow and python.Try to update tensorflow to their latest version.Follow theOfficial tensorflow installation guide to install latest version and let me know if you are still facing an issue,Thanks.
